# Build failed due to access denied in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I cannot build my project on retrying it shows this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz66x.png

Answer (score 0):

Try these operations and check after each step if the problem is solved.

1. Put a backslash (`\`) before every `'` in your `strings.xml` file
2. Clean and rebuild project, close Android Studio and run it again as administrator.
3. Delete AndroidStudio folder and reinstall it.